# Symfony 4 : How to manage login form with others forms on the same page?

Tags: forms, symfony, authentication

I have an article page with a twig condition.

If you want to commente my article, you must to login !

The login form is working but not redirect.

I have try a lot of things...

The profiler think, it's the comment form validation, but it's a loggin form validation.

Have you many ideas ?

With SF4 the controller for login is so poor, i don't success to manage it !

thx from France.

Comment: Please update your question to guide us through your problem, how to reproduce it and what you have already tried. What is the code in the controller? What are the error messages you get? Otherwise we have a hard time giving you actionable feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I assume your situation might be like this: when you check the user and it says anonymous you have a button "Log in to comment" which opens up a modal with login form so let's break it down first you must specify the login form action

```
<form action="{{ url('your_login_handler_url') }}" method="POST(I guess)">
{# here goes your form body #}
</form>
```

Next you should overwrite your authenticator used by your **/login** form(the function name and code is taken from [Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html))

```
class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
```

Here you must insert an if statment

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        // This one
        if($request->attributes->get('_route') === 'your article page') {
            return new RedirectResponse('your_article_page');
        }

        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('some_route'));
        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }
```

You might also want to override **onAuthenticationFailure** to redirect back to article page and not by default to the login page(although this might not be necessary I'm not 100% sure you might want to test it)

In this way your article comment form won't even know anything about the other form being submitted which will not result in validation error.